# Unable to set up sample React project correctly?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, material-ui

I got an interview assessment next week and they provided me a sample code project of what to expect. The problem is I'm having a LOT of trouble simply setting it up to run as expected...

Edited: Removed project for privacy

I cloned the project and installed all dependencies.

**Problem 1**
I followed the README in which I created a Database called messenger and then created a .env file in the *server* directory. The problem is I can't retrieve any values from that .env file through *process.env.REACT_APP_CUSTOM_VAR*. Console.logging "process.env" does not show ANY custom variables. It's as if they weren't even created...

**Problem 2**
On the frontend side, it should have been simple (npm install and then npm start). When starting, I found that there was NO CSS applied (despite reading the code and there's Material UI used). When I inspected the page, I'm getting the error 'The server responded with a status of 431 (Request header fields too large).

I have a hard time believing the company gave me super broken code to the point where I can't even  run the sample code properly... Can anyone please help me and try installing the code project above? Please let me know if you got the same problem or found any solutions!

Answer (score 0):

Submit an issue requesting that they add `.nvmrc` and `package-lock.json` such that you can ensure your machine is prepared to absorb dependencies and properly posture with the correct version of `node`. It's a crap-shoot of testing various versions of `node` against their build otherwise.

Your best bet is to check the first publish date of the client (javascript) code against the latest versions of node from that time. It sucks, but that's what I would do.

Comment: I think I did see a package-lock.json file there. It sounds like there's something wrong in my environment but I tried the same process and got the same broken result. Broken css, env variables not working, and even functionality (logging in with correct credentials) is all I'm getting...

Comment: I should've noted that these are all environment related. I polled my colleagues on their `npm` and `node` versions in our local development. Not a single colleague out of 13 front-end had the same versions. If the company was interested in finding talent and knew what they were looking for, they would signal on your knowledge of these facts.

Answer (score 0):

For the problem 1 on the server, I've create an .env file on the ./server directory and logging process.env logged the variables from that file. Also, on the backend, you don't need the REACT_APP_CUSTOM_VAR prefix when accessing environment variables.

For the problem 2 on the frontend, after the instalation, the client loaded the css from mui properly. I'm using node 14.17.0.

Comment: Sounds like my environment is the issue. I'm able to run the seed on the backend but only when I hardcode the DatabaseURL string myself in db.js instead of using environment variables. For the css, do you see any colors or styling at all? All I'm seeing is a broken form with no colors. Even when inputting the correct user credentials, it doesn't work... Any ideas on where I went wrong in my environment?

Answer (score 0):

The project runs fine.
Theres not really styling applied, but that seems to be intentional.

Most likely you would benefit from using whatever database you have access to that already works (in my case, mssql) by changing the db.js

```
const db = new Sequelize('dbname', 'user', 'password', {
  host: 'host',
  port: 1433,
  logging: false,
  dialect: 'mssql',
  dialectOptions: {
    encrypt: true,
  },
});
```

What you should however *not* do if you want the job, is critique it. It works just fine as the baseline for a recruitment assignment. Your enviroment is the issue in this case.

Do not forget to run the seed on the backend.

Comment: Sounds like my environment is the issue. I'm able to run the seed on the backend but only when I hardcode the DatabaseURL string myself in db.js instead of using environment variables. For the css, do you see any colors or styling at all? All I'm seeing is a broken form with no colors. Even when inputting the correct user credentials, it doesn't work... Any ideas on where I went wrong in my environment?

Comment: The credentials used are the names, not the email adresses. I logged in with thomas/123456 fine.
The form has absolutely no styling. The page after that has the bare minimum.
Where are you putting your .env file? in /server/.env, or somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, I'm tried to log in with julia/123456 and it fails. I can't even get past the login page. The form has no styling/colors at all but when I inspect the page, I could see the material UI components used. I put my .env file in /server since the instructions said to put it in the root directory of /server. Everyone here seems to be able to login fine and see the styling though...